# What's the probability that the ball (taken from the first box and dropped in the second box) was white?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have one pretty tricky question:

> There are two boxes. Each one has 7 balls: 3 white and 4 black. One
>   ball was taken from the first box and dropped in the second one. After
>   that, ball was taken from the second box and it was black. What's the
>   probability that the ball, that was taken from the first box and
>   dropped in the second one, was white?

I've tried solving it with combinatorics, and got the answer: 3/7 but it was not the right one.

Any help appreciate, Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that a Bayes rule question?

Comment: Please show how you arrived at your answer since that helps readers discern the source of any errors you may have made.

Comment: If we did not draw a second ball, we would be able to say based on the given information that the first ball was white with probability $3/7.$ So your conclusion is saying that the second ball gives us no new information at all about whether the second box ended up with four black balls or five after moving the first ball. That is not plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your calculation is somewhat off.

Tip: Evaluate the following

- $P(W_1)\qquad$ The probability of adding a white to the second jar.
- $P(B_2\mid W_1)$ The probability of extracting a black given that a white *had been **added** to the original 7*.
- $P(W_1^\complement)\qquad$ The probability of adding a black to the second jar,
- $P(B_2\mid W_1^\complement)$ The probability of extracting a black given that *a black had been added to the original 7*.

Then use Bayes' Rule: $$\mathsf P(W_1\mid B_2)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(W_1)\mathsf P(B_2\mid W_1)}{\mathsf P(W_1)\mathsf P(B_2\mid W_1)+\mathsf P(W_1^\complement)\mathsf P(B_2\mid W_1^\complement)}$$